# load html code into div, css not being applied

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an HTML page called index.html with 2 divs like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript">
        $('#menu1').click(function(){
            $("#content").load( "new_content.html" );
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li id="menu1">menu item 1</li>
                <li>menu item 2</li>
                <li>menu item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            Hello World
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also have a second html page called new_content.html containing this:

```
<h1>This is new content</h1>
<span class="blue">This line should be blue</span><br />
<span class="red">This line should be red</span>
```

The mystyle.css file contains this:

```
.blue {
    color: blue;
}

.red {
    color: red;
}
```

The 1st problem I encounter only happens in chrome, the 2nd problem in all browsers.
When I click the 'menu item 1' list element, the content div gets updated and I see the H1 title and the 2 lines underneath it, but I get the following 2 problems:

1. The two line are black, the css does not get applied
2. When I use the view source by right clicking in the browser, the content div contains the old code, namely "Hello World".

So I am somewhat baffled by this as I can clearly see the H1 title and the 2 lines under it, but no css is applied and the browser seems to think that no changes have taken place.

Maybe I am missing something, I am pretty new to jQuery, and maybe the load() function is not intended to be used this way.

I would appreciate any enlightenment you may be able to provide on this subject.

Regards
Crouz

Comment: what is your css for the first page? ie: menu, ul's li's

Comment: does the css work for the initial content? i.e., what happen when you replace the `Hello World` by a colored span?

Comment: @Keith The css is only what you see there. It is contained within the head tag of the index.html page.

Comment: It's entirely normal for ``view source`` to act that way. It states it shows you the source for the page, which doesn't actually change after a page load. What *does* change is the DOM. To inspect this, use your favorite developer tools to inspect some elements (F12 by default in most browsers)

Comment: @subsub, yes it does work. It actually works well in IE and firefox once I click the menu item 1, but not in chrome

Comment: In Chrome at least, viewing the source code yields the **original** source code, not the current one representing the current DOM. In Chrome go to Developer Tools and inspect elements in the Elements tab.

Comment: @Kippi understood, thanks. I can see the changes in dev tools. Still no css applied though.

Comment: What does the Computed Style tab in Dev Tools tell you in Chrome?

Comment: @devnull69 the css seems correct

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code in IE10, FF, Chrome, Safari and the CSS was working fine in all of them.
(I copied everything to my local machine)

about problem 1: make sure you load your CSS file correctly. [maybe you have a path problem]
you can check it very quickly by assigning `class="blue"` to some of the content that exists before the external loading, and see if it applies.

something like:

```
    <ul>
        <li id="menu1" class="blue">menu item 1</li>
        <li>menu item 2</li>
        <li>menu item 3</li>
    </ul>
```

about problem 2: this is totally normal, the HTML source code is the original HTML, only your DOM has changed. -you can see those changes via page inspector in any browser.

EDIT: (because of your comments)

apparently, this is caused by  browser cash (your browser saved an old styling when everything was black)
refresh the page with CTRL+F5 to reload everything.

and also, regarding 'load': (from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/))

> Additional Notes:
>
> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#contentPagina').load(nombrePagina,function(){ $('#contentPagina').trigger('create'); });
```